# Google Sheets array formula calculate sum column A:A

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, cumulative-sum

I need a simple array formula that calculates the sum from $A$2 to the column in A:A in array formula
the picture explains everything
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it ^_^

```
`=arrayformula(SI(A1:A="Number";"Total";SOMME.SI(LIGNE(A1:A);"<="&LIGNE(A1:A);A1:A)))`
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Total"; IF(A2:A="",, SUMIF(ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A), A2:A))})
```

[image: 3]